# show the result of an asynchronous method in the inner HTML

Tags: javascript, html, async-await, innerhtml

hello everyone I have a question, how can I show the result of an asynchronous method in the inner HTML?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    let y="";

 async function handlePress(){
 const URL = "https://ewserver.di.unimi.it/mobicomp/treest/register.php"
 console.log("Sending request")
const c= await fetch(URL);
return await c.json(); 
 }
function loadData(){
   this.handlePress().then(sids => {
    document.getElementById("#demo").innerHTML = sids;
  });
}
loadData()
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

in the inner HTML I want to print the result of the function handlePress().How can i do? to console, it tells me that innerHTML is empty.Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById` argument doesn't allow `#`

`innerHTML` have to be a string

```js
let y = "";

async function handlePress() {
  const URL = "https://ewserver.di.unimi.it/mobicomp/treest/register.php"
  console.log("Sending request")
  const c = await fetch(URL);
  return await c.json();
}

function loadData() {
  this.handlePress().then(sids => {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sids.sid
  });
}
loadData()
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: thank you. # I've seen it used as an argument within querySelector. eg: document.querySelector ("# id"). it's correct? # I can also use it as an argument inside other functions besides querySelector () ?

Comment: `querySelector`'s arguments mimic css selectors, this also works with `querySelectorAll`. `querySelector` is much newer than `getElementById`